# how to show correctly svg mask in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg, mask

i want to mask a svg on text for showing data, but in chrome not show correctly
i create svg with mask and its work perfectly in firefox, but in chrome not working
i want to apply mask on text for transparent show text in scroll

**HTML :**

```
    <div class="content">
    <div class="xx">
    <p>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text</p>
    </div>
       <svg>
        <defs>
          <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
            <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="40%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="60%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,255);stop-opacity:1" />
            <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0);stop-opacity:1" />
          </linearGradient>

          <mask id="masking" maskUnits="objectBoundingBox" maskContentUnits="objectBoundingBox">
             <rect width="1" height="1" fill="url(#grad1)"/>
          </mask>
       </defs>
     </svg>
    </div>
```

**CSS :**

```
    <style>
    .xx {
      mask: url(#masking);
    }
    body{
      background: red
    }

    .content{
      width:300px;
      height:200px;
    }
    .xx{
      height:200px;
      overflow-y:scroll;
    }.xx {
      mask: url(#masking);
    }
    body{
      background: red
    }

    .content{
      width:300px;
      height:200px;
    }
    .xx{
      height:200px;
      overflow-y:scroll;
    }
    </style>
```

[jsfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/gsxjdopd/)

Answer (score -1):

Chrome doesn't support `mask` on HTML elements.  However it does support `mask-image`.

[See the caniuse site for more information](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-masks).